# UCP install on docker EE fails: Node docker-ee-test is not ready yet

Tags: docker, docker-engine

I've installed `docker EE`.
Now I'm trying to setup `docker ucp`:

```
docker container run --rm -it --name ucp   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   docker/ucp:3.0.1 install  --pod-cidr 10.0.0.0/16 --host-address 192.168.140.131   --interactive
```

output:

```
xxx@docker-ee-test:~$ docker container run --rm -it \
>     --name ucp \
>     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
>     docker/ucp \
>     install --pod-cidr 10.0.0.0/16  --interactive
INFO[0000] Your engine version 17.06.2-ee-11, build 06fc007 (4.13.0-1017-gcp) is compatible with UCP 3.0.1 (2f7c7e1)
Admin Username: xxx
Admin Password:
Confirm Admin Password:
INFO[0006] Pulling required images... (this may take a while)
INFO[0006] Pulling docker/ucp-cfssl:3.0.1
INFO[0009] Pulling docker/ucp-etcd:3.0.1
INFO[0012] Pulling docker/ucp-auth:3.0.1
INFO[0015] Pulling docker/ucp-compose:3.0.1
INFO[0028] Pulling docker/ucp-hyperkube:3.0.1
INFO[0039] Pulling docker/ucp-calico-node:3.0.1
INFO[0046] Pulling docker/ucp-kube-dns-dnsmasq-nanny:3.0.1
INFO[0050] Pulling docker/ucp-metrics:3.0.1
INFO[0054] Pulling docker/ucp-swarm:3.0.1
INFO[0057] Pulling docker/ucp-dsinfo:3.0.1
INFO[0059] Pulling docker/ucp-pause:3.0.1
INFO[0060] Pulling docker/ucp-agent:3.0.1
INFO[0067] Pulling docker/ucp-auth-store:3.0.1
INFO[0072] Pulling docker/ucp-kube-compose:3.0.1
INFO[0074] Pulling docker/ucp-kube-dns-sidecar:3.0.1
INFO[0077] Pulling docker/ucp-interlock-proxy:3.0.1
INFO[0080] Pulling docker/ucp-interlock:3.0.1
INFO[0081] Pulling docker/ucp-calico-cni:3.0.1
INFO[0086] Pulling docker/ucp-calico-kube-controllers:3.0.1
INFO[0093] Pulling docker/ucp-interlock-extension:3.0.1
INFO[0095] Pulling docker/ucp-controller:3.0.1
INFO[0101] Pulling docker/ucp-kube-dns:3.0.1
WARN[0109] None of the hostnames we'll be using in the UCP certificates [docker-ee-test 127.0.0.1 172.17.0.1] contain a domain component.  Your generated certs may fail TLS validation unless you only use one of these shortnames or IPs to connect.  You can use the --san flag to add more aliases

You may enter additional aliases (SANs) now or press enter to proceed with the above list.
Additional aliases:
INFO[0000] Initializing a new swarm at 10.132.0.2
INFO[0012] Installing UCP with host address 10.132.0.2 - If this is incorrect, please specify an alternative address with the '--host-address' flag
INFO[0012] Deploying UCP Service...
ERRO[0656] Unable to successfully setup local node. Run "docker logs ucp-reconcile" for more details
FATA[0656] reconcile exited with non-zero status: 1
```

It fails:
logs tell me:

```
{"level":"info","msg":"Node docker-ee-test is not ready yet, waiting","time":"2018-05-26T12:05:37Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Node docker-ee-test is not ready yet, waiting","time":"2018-05-26T12:05:39Z"}
```

containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                                                             NAMES
fd1db7b339da        docker/ucp-agent:3.0.1        "/bin/ucp-agent re..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes              2376/tcp                                                                          ucp-reconcile
94b731b8326b        docker/ucp-agent:3.0.1        "/bin/ucp-agent agent"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes              2376/tcp                                                                          ucp-agent.zi98dfn3y4iw9im9nitdstusp.hqi1ai1eqh6usoga4obv6637y
883f2ef3f388        docker/ucp-hyperkube:3.0.1    "/bin/apiserver_en..."   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes             0.0.0.0:6443->6443/tcp                                                            ucp-kube-apiserver
38ac4cd17032        docker/ucp-controller:3.0.1   "/bin/controller s..."   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:443->8080/tcp                                                             ucp-controller
b4611492635d        docker/ucp-swarm:3.0.1        "/bin/swarm manage..."   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:2376->2375/tcp                                                            ucp-swarm-manager
f41c696539c4        docker/ucp-hyperkube:3.0.1    "kube-controller-m..."   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes (healthy)                                                                                     ucp-kube-controller-manager
cc02d6bd5e56        docker/ucp-auth:3.0.1         "/usr/local/bin/en..."   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:12385->4443/tcp                                                           ucp-auth-api
32d6b64bb9df        docker/ucp-auth:3.0.1         "/usr/local/bin/en..."   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:12386->4443/tcp                                                           ucp-auth-worker
22351abdc26a        docker/ucp-hyperkube:3.0.1    "kube-scheduler --..."   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes (healthy)                                                                                     ucp-kube-scheduler
362b466eda28        docker/ucp-auth-store:3.0.1   "rethinkdb --bind ..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:12383-12384->12383-12384/tcp                                              ucp-auth-store
664516a879b7        docker/ucp-cfssl:3.0.1        "/bin/ucp-ca serve..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:12382->12382/tcp                                                          ucp-client-root-ca
84dea814be16        docker/ucp-cfssl:3.0.1        "/bin/ucp-ca serve..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:12381->12381/tcp                                                          ucp-cluster-root-ca
69491664323e        docker/ucp-hyperkube:3.0.1    "kube-proxy --clus..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes                                                                                               ucp-kube-proxy
74d7cf32e1d6        docker/ucp-metrics:3.0.1      "/bin/entrypoint.s..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:12387->12387/tcp                                                          ucp-metrics
bde445bbe390        docker/ucp-hyperkube:3.0.1    "kubelet --allow-p..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes                                                                                               ucp-kubelet
dab50a0ada23        docker/ucp-etcd:3.0.1         "/bin/entrypoint.s..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes (healthy)   2380/tcp, 4001/tcp, 7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12380->12380/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12379->2379/tcp   ucp-kv
f9072dee881c        docker/ucp-agent:3.0.1        "/bin/ucp-agent pr..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6444->6444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12378->12378/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12376->2376/tcp         ucp-proxy
```

what am I missing? I tried it locally and in the cloud? firewalls are open.

for hyperkube I see this log:

```
W0526 13:41:59.818800   16664 cni.go:196] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
E0526 13:41:59.819179   16664 kubelet.go:2095] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

syslog:

```
May 26 15:35:23 lorenz-virtual-machine NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1527341723.8322] device (vethb8aee1c): driver 'veth' does not support carrier detection.
May 26 15:35:23 lorenz-virtual-machine NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1527341723.8326] device (veth8c75c4e): driver 'veth' does not support carrier detection.
May 26 15:35:23 lorenz-virtual-machine NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1527341723.8651] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethb8aee1c, iface: vethb8aee1c)
May 26 15:35:23 lorenz-virtual-machine NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1527341723.8827] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth8c75c4e, iface: veth8c75c4e)
May 26 15:35:23 lorenz-virtual-machine dockerd[1717]: time="2018-05-26T15:35:23.932057395+02:00" level=error msg="plugin not found"
May 26 15:35:30 lorenz-virtual-machine dockerd[1717]: time="2018-05-26T15:35:30.227253060+02:00" level=error msg="plugin not found"
May 26 15:36:15 lorenz-virtual-machine dockerd[1717]: time="2018-05-26T15:36:15.266790568+02:00" level=error msg="plugin not found"
May 26 15:37:00 lorenz-virtual-machine dockerd[1717]: time="2018-05-26T15:37:00.578404347+02:00" level=error msg="plugin not found"
```

Comment: The 'fix' was to provide more CPU